# Coin flipping - returning random outcome

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, probability

forgive me if this was already posted :) I have had a problem stuck in my head all day which I have been trying to think of an efficient solution for. Basically the problem is this: Imagine you have to flip a coin 3 billion times and would like a function that returns the amount of heads after all these flips. One possible solution would be to obviously make a for loop iterating 3 billion times recording how many heads and tails and returning the heads - this is obviously an incredibly inefficient solution. I thought of binomial probability but could not see where this could come in to help solve this problem (i'm probably missing something really obvious).

For example say I input in the function NumberOfHeads(flips) most the time (statistically) it will likely return some number around flips / 2. However say flips = 3 billion there should still be a chance that (although incredibly slim to never) it may return 1000 heads or something. Hope I explained whats been troubling me well enough :) thanks for any reponses.

Comment: This would be a probability question -- calculate the probability of 1 head, 2 heads, 3 heads... etc, and then use those probabilities and randomly choose between them once. Look up the probability of a simpler problem, like for 10 flips, then use that format to calculate the list of probabilities for `n` flips. After getting the list of probabilities, it's like rolling a die with that number of sides with different weights.

Comment: With a number like 3 billion flips, you'd use a [gaussian approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation).

Comment: Sorry this is unclear. I know how to calculate the probability and it's not what i'm asking for. I'm wanting some function that will return a random output of the number of heads over a certain number of flips. For example NumberOfHeads(10) or 10 flips will mostly return 4 to 6 but will have a chance of returning say 0.

Comment: I am not looking to simulate all 3 billion flips (as I mentioned it being inefficient) perhaps some mathematical function that is most likely to return a number say within the range of the standard deviation.

Comment: You'd still use a gaussian approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scipy.stats.binom` here.  The function below returns the number of heads from a randomly sampled binomial distribution with fair coin flips at each (bernoulli) trial.

```
import scipy.stats as scs
def num_heads(num_flips):
    flips = scs.binom(n=num_flips, p=0.5)
    return np.asscalar(flips.rvs(1))

num_heads(3000000000)
# 1499985766
```

`.rvs()` here stands for *random variate*.

Without looking through the source, I'm going to guess random number generation is using the analytic binomial CDF *p=CDF(x)*, taking the inverse CDF, then choosing *p* from a ~U(0,1) distribution.  You can read more about that method in Downey - ThinkStats - section 5.6.  Disclosure: I might be totally wrong, as I often am.